# Using objects and object functions through variables

Tags: c++, class, object

Background of the program: the user is able to input a `string` of two words only - a verb and a noun. I tokenize this string into a `vector` and compare `tokens[0]` with a `vector` of allowed verbs, and `tokens[1]` with a `vector` of allowed nouns.

Now, I'm trying to find a way to allow only certain verbs to be performed on certain nouns. For example, writing "take book" will give a message (or whatever) saying it's allowed, but writing "take door" would not be. I have so far created a `class` Object with `bool` values for each possible verb (eg. within the `class Object`, I can create an `Object book` for which `m_take = true`, or `false` for an `Object door`).

However, I'm having trouble associating these objects with the user input. For example, I would like to be able to do something like this: 
1) User inputs "verb noun", which go into the tokens vector as `tokens[0]` and `tokens[1]`.
2) Program checks if the input contains acceptable words (individually).
3) Considering `getstat()` to be the function to retreive the bool value of the possible action doable on an object, the program retrieves `tokens[1].getstat(tokens[0])` and, if `true`, executes `tokens[0].tokens[1]()` (eg. `book.take()`). This way I could have only one `if` cycle in my `main()`, which can be used by all legal verbs and nouns, without making an infinite list of `if`, `else if`, etc, considering every single option manually.

Sorry if this is at all confusing. I know it is not possible to use a variable as an object name, but I'm sure there's a better way to do this than doing cycles within cycles of considering every single mix and match of verb and noun. I'm experimenting with like 3 each at the moment, but once I get this working I plan on expanding it and it would be a nightmare to keep track of every change if I have to hard-code every possible verb and noun multiple times within the source code. (Also, sorry for not posting the whole source - it's a really long file just now!)
Thanks for any help/hint in the right direction!

Comment: You may want to read up on the concept of **pointer to member** (maybe also on virtual functions).

Answer (score 2):

You could use runtime polymorphism for this kind of stuff, either with `virtual` methods or C++11 `std::function` and lambdas.

You will obviously have to redesign your *"token"* system.

---

Virtual methods example:

```
struct Object
{ 
    virtual void onTake() { }
    virtual void onOpen() { }
};

struct Door : public Object 
{
    bool open{false};
    void onTake() override { say("I can't take the door!"); }
    void onOpen() override { say("The door is now open."); open = true; }
};

struct Book : public Object
{
    void onTake() override { say("I put the book in my backpack."); }
    void onOpen() override { say("I open the book. All the pages are blank."); }
};
```

---

C++11 lambdas example:

```
struct Object
{ 
    std::function<void()> onTake, onOpen;
};

struct Door : public Object 
{
    bool open{false};
    Door() 
    {
        onTake = []{ say("I can't take the door!"); };
        onOpen = []{ say("The door is now open."); open = true; };
    }
};

struct Book : public Object
{
    Book() 
    {
        onTake = []{ say("I put the book in my backpack."); };
        onOpen = []{ say("I open the book. All the pages are blank."); };
    }
};

// You can also avoid creating new classes
Object bananaPrototype; 
bool eaten{false};
bananaPrototype.onTake = []{ say("I put the banana in my backpack."); };
bananaPrototype.onOpen = [eaten] mutable 
{ say("I eat the banana. Yum."); eaten = true; };
```

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, thank you! I have never used any of this before (haven't used `structs` before either) but it seems like it would do what I would need it to, so I will look into it. Thanks! Just one question though, how would I link this to the user input? How can I make the program call `struct Door` from the `string` "door", or call `onTake` from `string` "take"? Would I have to create a list of ifs to assign one to the other for all possible objects or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Ok, I've been looking at this to try and make it work for what I'm doing, and it might be a really stupid question, but what do you mean by "say", as in `void onTake() override { say("I can't take the door!"); }` ? I've tried to google it to see if it was part of something I have not included, but can't find it anywhere. Thanks :)

Comment: It's all pseudocode. `say` is an imaginary function that says something. Use `cout<<` instead or whatever you have.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense - had a feeling it was a stupid question :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an advice in such a non trivial case not seeing the code, but, as far as I understand, you'd better consider dropping the hardcode approach, i.e.
`book.take()`.
Try writing more generic code, at least something like `book.action(actions::kTake)`.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, `tokens[0].tokens[1]()` does not do what you want it to - the names of functions and variables are not available when the program is being run.

You could try using maps. `objects` could be a map with keys of the object names. The values (`objects[token[0]]`) would in turn be other maps which would be functions to do what you want  (`objects[token[0]][token[1]]`).

Here is an example:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void read_fn()
{
    cout << "You read the book";
}

int main()
{
    unordered_map <string, unordered_map <string, void (*)()>> lookup;

    unordered_map <string, void (*)()> book_lookup;

    book_lookup["read"] = read_fn;
    lookup["book"] = book_lookup;

    lookup["book"]["read"]();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't thought I could use maps. I will try pairing verbs and nouns in a map and then looking up the input words in the map to see if a relevant pair is found.